# r.mfilter not applying to raster map

Tags: raster, grass-gis, filter

I tried applying r.mfilter to my raster map and it is saying error and not creating any filtered layer. I have tried closing the app and redid project again and upgraded grass as well but still the layer is not being created.

Comment: Are you using Grass through QGIS ?

Comment: Also please post: `r.info` for the raster map,  the command you ran, and the error message that you got.

Comment: And, did you set the https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region properly to the input raster map?